Nextjs build issue when using dynamic route
In the developmemt mode the website is working perfectly with dynamic route like post/[postid] ie post/122 but as I tried to build it using npm run dev I get error as getStaticProps is not added .... I am trying to build it as my backend is custom not nextjs server and I have to render pages from my backend(example expressjs) how to do so it there a way. My route is app way not page way
I read that dynamic routes are not possible as client side (not sure)... But I need html after build so that I can send those pages from my server.
